Using unicode characters in Power Automate Online Excel Filter Queries
I have an Excel "List rows present in a table" action in Power Automate online with the ODATA filter query  eq 'x', as the Excel column is named with the unicode character  (U+1F5B6), but it either gets stuck in the action when I launch it or it returns no results despite having cells with an "x" value.
Is there any way of making the special character work in the filter query?
If I change the column name and query to something with like print eq 'x' it does work, but I'd prefer to keep the special character.
Cheers
Edit: I have noticed that some special characters get encoded in the json request, but unicode characters do not:
      {
            "@odata.etag": "",
            "unicodeinvalue": "✔",             
            "": "unicodeinpropertyname",
            "Point_x002e_": "The actual column name is 'Point.'"            
        }


you can encode a unicode character using the uriComponent() function:
so instead of using  eq 'x' you can:
Create a compose action with the following expression:
uriComponent('')

Then your filter query: outputs('Compose') eq 'x'

I've tried a couple ways and both give me an error. If I paste the whole thing to the filter query textbox, I get a Bad Request (unknown function with name 'uricomponent' was found). If I add uriComponent('') part using the insert formula wizard, I get "Syntax error: character '%' is not valid at position 0 in '%F0%9F%96%B6 eq 'x''". Trying to add the whole expression with the wizard with either eq 'x' or equals(uriComponent(''),'x') does not seem to work either.

I updated my answer, you can try to use a compose first

I have tried that, then referencing the output in the filter textbox ("@{outputs('Compose')} eq 'x'") and it throws the same error as before when running the flow: "
Action 'List_rows_present_in_a_table' failed: Syntax error: character '%' is not valid at position 0 in '%F0%9F%96%B6 eq 'x''. inner exception: Syntax error: character '%' is not valid at position 0 in '%F0%9F%96%B6 eq 'x''."

that is interesting... what if you just put the character in quotes '' eq 'x'

It throws the error "Action 'List_rows_present_in_a_table' failed: Invalid filter clause: unsupported operation. Only single 'eq', 'ne', 'contains', 'startswith' or 'endswith' is currently supported.". Using it without quotes just gets the flow permanently stuck on the action and I have to manually cancel it (with the old designer it gets stuck at "1 retries occurred", but it does not stop). I am trying to get the column id from the Get a Row action but does not work either. In the JSONs it appears like "": "x", or "idColumn": "". I do not know why the filter does not recognize it.

if it appears in double quotes in the json you could try that. Otherwise, i may be out of ideas

Tried too, throws an error. =)
